# How to generate "Unbalanced" (unequal) factor levels in Base?

Tags: r, function, anova, t-test

## Background:

I usually use `gl()` to generate "equal" number of factor levels for a set of random variables. For example, to generate `2` factor levels for `60` random variables in `x`, I use the following:

```
x = rnorm(n = 60)
groups = gl( 2, length(x)/2 ) ## My Factor Levels
```

But above, doesn't allow me to produce, say, `40` factor levels for the first `40` elements in `x`, and `20` factor levels for the last `20` elements in `x` (i.e., ***"Unbalanced" (unequal) factor levels***).

## Question:

**In base R,** is there a flexible function or a strategy to produce "Unbalanced" (unequal) factor levels?

Comment: `as.factor(rep(1:2, each=40, length.out=length(x)))` could accomplish the 40/20 case

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer, thanks, so no other flexible R function to your knowledge exist for this purpose, right?

Comment: think simon has you covered with his answer using `rep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rep` with a vector-valued `times` argument:

```
x <- factor( rep(1:3, times=c(5,10,2)) )
x
```

This gives:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
Levels: 1 2 3
```